# Why does matlab causes terminal std out crash and how do I fix it?

Tags: matlab, shell, terminal, stdout

Every time when I finish running a matlab code collection on command line, when I exit matlab, the standard output just gets messed. I can still use the terminal window, but whatever I typed won't show up on the screen, leaving me either type with my eyes blind, or open up a new terminal and excessively `cd` to the old place.

This happens every single time when I use `make` to run a matlab collection, and since I'm working a lot on this, it turns out to be very annoying. Does anyone know what's the problem here and how should I fix it?

Comment: try typing `stty sane`, does it help?  If it helps it means that something in your makescript is dumping binary data onto the terminal, that messes up the terminal's config.  stty sane restores the config.

Comment: Great.  Now you just have to figure out what part of the script is actually messing up the terminal.

Comment: This is my Makefile code: `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r run`. I don't really see where it's dumping anything to shell though.

Comment: Must be the matlab process itself then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the makescript is probably dumping "bad" characters to the terminal. You could prevent this (but possibly lose useful information) by redirecting the output - instead of sending it to the terminal window, you can send it to a file, or even `/dev/null` ("the great bit bucket in the sky").

The underlying problem, however, is that your makefile is even sending these characters to the terminal in the first place. I would recommend that you pipe the output to a file with something like `make > myDump.txt`, then examine the resulting file to see what is going on, and where in your makefile the problem is created. It is possible that you will still be getting some output when you do this - that's because by default `>` redirects `stdout` only, and not `stderr` - a second output stream used for error messages. You can redirect both to a file with `make 2>&1 myDump.txt`.

You have already seen the recommendation to use `stty sane` to restore the status of the terminal - I am repeating it here in case someone only looks at answers, and not at comments; but I don't take credit for it :-).